# Neural Network that returns multiple classifications in one output - Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

**Tensorflow 2.0.0**

**python 3.7.6**

I'm trying to solve a problem that given a number of inputs it returns multiple classifications in one output. For example, given the input `[1, 0, 3000, 200, 250, ... 0, 1]`, it can return an output that would look like this `[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, ... 0, 0]`. There are about 319 possible labels, and there can be 1 to 7 of them active in one output as above. In addition, I also want to know quantity, so the output could look like `[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, ..., 1]`.

After some reading, I came up with the following model

```py
...

# This is how i'm normalizing the inputs
train_input = np.array(tf.keras.utils.normalize(input, axis = 1, order = 2).tolist())
test_input = np.array(tf.keras.utils.normalize(test_input, axis = 1, order = 2).tolist())

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(230, input_shape=(26,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(319, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(319, activation='linear'),
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_input, train_output, validation_data=(test_input, test_output), epochs = 50)

...
```

I read that since I want multiple labels in one output, the activation function for the output layer should be 'linear'. Also, since I want quantities as an output the loss function should be 'mean square error'. My data set is about 16k.

This network did not perform well. The highest accuracy it could reach. after some tweaks, is about 15%. I figured I was being too ambitious by trying to get quantities and classifications on the same output. I decided to create 7 different similar networks and have the output look more like a traditional classification (only one label active per output `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]`). That model looks like this

```py
...

train_input = np.array(tf.keras.utils.normalize(input, axis = 0, order = 2).tolist())
test_input = np.array(tf.keras.utils.normalize(test_input, axis = 0, order = 2).tolist())

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(230, input_shape=(26,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(319, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(319, activation='softmax'),
])

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_input, train_output, validation_data=(test_input, test_output), epochs = 20)
```

This network, with not much optimization, can achieve about 60% (this is not great, but its a much better start). However, this is not ideal as it would not show me quantity and since the 7 outputs are related, It seems to be better to have them in one network.

All this being said, I would like some guidance to improve my original network. What architecture would work better? Is it too much to get a network to classify through quantity? Should I continue the 7 network approach? Any useful readings/tips?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understood correctly, you have only 14K examples to train your model, right? I am afraid that it is usually a very low number for tuning a deep neural net model. On the other hand, although you did not detail your problem and the features you have, fro the output you try to get ( of dim > 300), you normally would need a much deeper network! and again you will need more data! Those are my fast guesses by the way

Comment: I figured I would need more data, but was looking for confirmation. I'm interested in understanding some of the architectural changes I would need to make. When you say my network would need to be deeper, how could I determine how deep it should be? Maybe a ball park?